# Calling managed bean methods in JavaScript in with normal HTML button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to call managed bean methods in JavaScript while clicking the normal HTML button. Is it possible to do that, provided that I use JSF2.x and Primefaces?

Comment: what do you mean by `calling managed bean api`?

Comment: if i click the html button ,i need to invoke JSF managedbean's method.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `<h:commandButton>` instead of normal button?

Comment: This is my scenario.i didn't use <h:XXXX> any thing. because i get all html tags directly.

Comment: Please post the related code then help will be easy

Comment: If you have just HTML tags where are you using JSF and PrimeFaces!? An show your page code and code of backing bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Primefaces provides for a useful hook to do that with its component [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf). It basically offers you with a javascript function that will be able to communicate with your bean.

Basic usage example:

The view:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remote" actionListener="#{bean.listener}" update="text"/>
<h:outputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}/>
<div onclick="remote()">...<div>
```

The bean:

```
private String text = "Starting text";//getter + setter

public void listener(ActionEvent event) {
    text = "Text was changed via remote command";
}
```

In the above example the remote command is executed whenever your `<div>` is clicked. Of course, the same function could be called by clicking on your button.

Also, it would be wise to check out the [Primefaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Great answer.  Took a while for me to figure out that a javascript function is automatically created based on the p:remoteCommand name that you assign it, and it must match with the div onclick method... btw you can change the name "remote" to whatever name you want, for creating multiple commands.